# Don't Know How To Join Using Calculation and a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not know how to join tables based on a calculation. I have to take a substring to get the part of a string I need to match up to a column from another table. I cannot figure out how to join them and really don't know where to start.

I tried everything in my power but I literally took a beginner's class and now have to fend for myself.

```
Select *
From five9_data.calllog join warbird.user
ON warbird.attr_employee = substring(five9_data.calllog.agent, 4,position('@' in five9_data.calllog.agent)- 4)
Group By warbird.attr_employee
Order warbird.attr_employee
Limit 100
```

I tried the above in the Select command but figured out it will not work and that I need to use the calculations in the join statement, but have no idea on syntax/formula. A few examples made as simple as possible would be great. I also have issue with the Group By Order by with this.

Shown above.

Comment: `A few examples made as simple as possible would be great` ... actually you are the one who needs to show us sample data, along with your current query.  Otherwise, you might not get an answer here.

Comment: `join otherTbl o on o.id = substring(agent, 4,position('@' in agent)- 4)`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will try to put the query together and put it back in.

Comment: Select *
From five9_data as f join warbird as w
ON w.attr_employee_= substring(f.agent, 4,position('@' in f.agent)- 4)
Group By f.date, w.attr_employee        Now I am getting issues with the group By Order by. Apologize for knowing so little and asking but all help is appreciated

Comment: There is no reason to use GROUP BY when your not calling an aggregate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, the `join` condition would look like:

```
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.empid = concat('%', t2.agent, '%')
```

Or, you can just use the expression:

```
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.empid = substring(t2.agent, 4, position('@' in t2.agent) - 4)
```

EDIT:

As for your example code, I would write it as:

```
Select b.attr_employee, . . .   -- aggregation functions go here
From five9_data.calllog cl join
     warbird.user u
     on u.attr_employee = substring(cl.agent, 4, position('@' in cl.calllog.agent) - 4)
Group By u.attr_employee
Order u.attr_employee
Limit 100;
```

Here are changes to notice:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- When using `GROUP BY`, the only unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should be the `GROUP BY` keys.  The rest should be aggregated.
- Your problem is that `warbird.attr_employee` is not defined, because you have missed the table name.  However, `u` is so much easier to write and to read.

Comment: Are there conditions I must use for Order By Group By

Answer (score 0):

```sql
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.empid = substring(t2.agent, 4, position('@' in t2.agent) - 4)
```